# How to hide inactive images in jQuery image cycler

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using a plugin to cycle stacked batches of images by fading them in / out and setting the correct z-indexes. It works as intended, except that inactive images are visible behind the active ones. This is an issue because my images are not completely the same height and width.

How can I fix it - either by adding some jQuery or css?

Adding `display: none` to each batch didn't work. [JsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0sh1Lwga/20/).

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="batch">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/450/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/620/460/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="batch">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/430/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/420/any">
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="batch">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.rotator = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      blocks: '.batch',
      speed: 6000,
      fadeSpeed: 800
    }, options);
    var setZIndex = function(element) {
      var index = $(options.blocks, element).length;
      $(options.blocks, element).each(function() {
        index--;
        $(this).css('zIndex', index);
      });
    };
    var rotate = function(element) {
      var blocks = $(options.blocks, element),
        len = blocks.length,
        index = -1;
      blocks.fadeIn(options.fadeSpeed);
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        index++;
        var block = blocks.eq(index);
        if (index == len) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          rotate(element);
        }
        if (block.index() != (len - 1)) {
          block.fadeOut(options.fadeSpeed);
        }
      }, options.speed);
    };
    return this.each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      setZIndex(elem);
      rotate(elem);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
$('#wrapper').rotator();
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
  height: 185px;
  position: relative;
}

.batch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.batch>a {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.batch>a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your JS function is dependent on `z-index` and not on `display`, I hiding images will take some more efforts and it will also not help you with aspect ratio of the image. Try adding `height: 100%;` and `object-position: center;` to your `img` and you will get an answer somewhat close to your requirement.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.rotator = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
      blocks: '.batch',
      speed: 6000,
      fadeSpeed: 800
    }, options);
    var setZIndex = function(element) {
      var index = $(options.blocks, element).length;
      $(options.blocks, element).each(function() {
        index--;
        $(this).css('zIndex', index);
      });
    };
    var rotate = function(element) {
      var blocks = $(options.blocks, element),
        len = blocks.length,
        index = -1;
      blocks.fadeIn(options.fadeSpeed);
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        index++;
        var block = blocks.eq(index);
        if (index == len) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          rotate(element);
        }
        if (block.index() != (len - 1)) {
          block.fadeOut(options.fadeSpeed);
        }
      }, options.speed);
    };
    return this.each(function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      setZIndex(elem);
      rotate(elem);
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
$('#wrapper').rotator();
```

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 185px;
  position: relative;
}

.batch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.batch>a {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.batch>a img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="batch">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/450/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/620/460/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="batch">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/430/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/420/any">
  </a>
  </div>
  <div class="batch">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps